# Array used for an inventory like 'Apples' = 99 in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, inventory

I have researched different ways of creating arrays and how to use lists, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I made a program in python that does what I want, but python cuts alot of corners and I would like to know the "proper" and most efficient way of doing this.

I want to create an array (or list, not sure what's best for this) that has a string like 'Potion' and an int for the amount of that item, like an inventory for a game. What would be the best way to implement this?

I noticed you can make arrays like: Inventory.InvArray[][]
But how can I make the first element a string, and the second element an int?

As you can see I'm a little confused, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not looking for an array or list, but for a dictionary.

In .NET, you can use the generic [Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), e.g.

```
var inventory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
inventory["Apple"] = 99;
```

In Python, you would use a [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), e.g.

```python
inventory = dict()
inventory["Apple"] = 99
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Dictionary<string, int>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Or you could make an `Item` object with an integer `InventoryCount` property.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a map of key value pair, like in your case, use a generic Dictionary instead.

```
var inventory = new Dictionary<string, int>();
inventory.Add("potion", 20);
inventory.Add("apple", 99);
```

Here the string type is for your keys, in this case a string for potions or apples and the int type is for your values, in this case quantity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a strongly-typed `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  You can specify the types as `string` and `int`, like so:

```
Dictionary<string, int> YourCollection = new Dictionary<string, int> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `Dictionay<String, int>` ?